# Run swift example rather than objective c example

Tags: ios, swift

i have downloaded some projects from Gitub, but the project contains both objective and swift examples...

[image]

I wish to run the swift examples, not the objective example. How do i do that?

PS: i tried to delete the DatabaseExample and change the databaseexampleSwift to DatabaseExample, but i get a lot of errors.

Comment: Are there targets, near the choose simulator area?

Comment: If so click to choose from there which one to run.

Comment: @Aakash.. I think i get it already... Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there will be multiple schemes to the project, and changing the scheme will prevent the files of each language being linked respectively. Next to the device at the top, click the name of the app and see if there is a Swift option on that menu.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your project is structured, but a project can only be determined to run in Swift OR Objective-C.

Since you have downloaded the code, I recommend creating a new project, and in the create new project dialog box, choose Swift as the language for the project.

After that, you can drop the code in Swift in by using the arrow on the bottom left corner, then choose "Add files..." to add those files into the project.